# Trying to Pass Form Field Values To CFC via AJAX

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I have two form field:

```
<cfinput type="text" name="ticket_id" id="ticket_id" value="#get_ticket.ticket_id#" tabindex="1" readonly="readonly" />

<textarea class='expanding' tabindex="0" name="admin_notes" id="admin_notes" cols="100" rows="5">#get_ticket.admin_notes#</textarea>
```

I am trying to pass the values of those fields to a CFC function when I press this button.

```
<input type="button" name="addTechNotes" id="addTechNotes" value="Add New Note" />
```

Here is my AJAX call:

```
<!---Javascript for adding notes to ticket --->  
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      //Submit form to add record.
      $('#addTechNotes').click(function (e) 
      {          
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        data: {tech_notes : $("#tech_notes").val(), ticket_id : $("#ticket_id").val() },
        type:'POST',
        url:'../cfcs/add_ticket_notes.cfc?method=addNotes',
        success: function() {
        $("#addNotesMessage").append( "Note successfully entered." );

        error: console.log("error");
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click the botton my browser console logs: error (The error attribute of my AJAX call). What am I missing?

Here is my CFC:

```
<cffunction name="addNotes" access="remote" returnType="string">
<cfargument name="ticket_id" type="any" required="true">
<cfargument name="tech_notes" type="any" required="yes">

<!--- localize function variables --->
<cfset var dataDetail = "">
<cfoutput>
<cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
    update closed_tickets
    set tech_notes = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.tech_notes#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
    WHERE ticket_id = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.ticket_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
<cfreturn dataDetail>
```

Comment: What happens when you access the cfc URL in the browser? So far i see that in the CFC the returnType is string and you are returning  query...

Comment: And <cfset var dataDetail = ""> will give you an error...

Comment: Do I have to return anything? I just want to post the data to my DB for that record.

Comment: Actually, removing the <cfset> and <cfreturn> allows the CFC to run without throwing an error now.

Comment: Now as a problem isolated to the front end I'd put more descriptive error  handler. Try the code below to see if you get more info. 

error:function(response)    
        {
           console.log(response); 
        }

Comment: Just noticing you don't have `</cffunction>` at the bottom of your code. That might be your error, unless you just didn't copy that line here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ajax call was a little broken. Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Submit form to add record.
    $('#addTechNotes').click(function (e) {          
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                tech_notes : $("#tech_notes").val(), 
                ticket_id : $("#ticket_id").val()
            },
            type:"POST",
            url:"../cfcs/add_ticket_notes.cfc?method=addNotes",
            success: function() {
                $("#addNotesMessage").append( "Note successfully entered." );
            }, // CLOSE THE SUCCESS PARAM
            // START THE ERROR PARAM
            error: function() {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code with your suggestions but the weird thing is that it runs the CFC and updates the appropriate record but the console reports an error and runs the error: code.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error. My cfc was returning nothing. Added <cfreturn ticket_id > and now everything is wqorking properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea field has a name and id of 'admin_notes' but you're referencing an element with id of 'tech_notes' in the ajax call.

I also prefer to add quotes around my data string

```
data: '{tech_notes:\'' + $("#tech_notes").val() + '\', ticket_id: \'' + $("#ticket_id").val() + '\' }',
```